# Django Model Inheritance - Query parent model for 'unknown' relationship

Tags: python, django, inheritance, model

Take the following as an example:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)

class CarMixin(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    num_wheels = models.IntegerField()

class CellPhoneMixin(models.Model):
    screen_size = models.IntegerField()

class Car(Product, CarMixin):
    pass


class Food(Product):
    pass


class CellPhone(Product, CellPhoneMixin):
    pass
```

what I am trying to do is create a 'base' class called `Product` and apply a variety of 'sub-product-types' using [Model Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

The reason I am not using the Django's 'Abstract Model Inheritance' is because I actually want a table in my DB to hold all the products, so I can make a query like `Product.objects.all()` to get all the products, then type `product.car` to get all the field values for the related `Car` object.

However, the problem I am running into is that a product can have a relationship with any one of `Car`, `Food` or `CellPhone`. So, I can't do `product.car` if it has a relationship with `Food`.  There is no way in knowing which 'relationship' a Product object has.  Is it related to `Car`? `Food`? `CellPhone`?

How should I approach this?  Is there a better database schema I should be using?

Comment: What do you mean by 'relationship'? You can call `Car.objects.all()`

Comment: @BorrajaX The lowercase model name (e.g. `car`) will be the  related_name of the implicitly created `product_ptr` relation. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

Comment: `Product.objects.filter(car__isnull=False)`  will give you all Car Products.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Indeed... That's why I removed the comment (saw the docs after I wrote it)...

Comment: Can I ask why you're creating separate models for `Car`, `Food`, etc? You seem to have a `Category` model, so why not create categories for `Car`, `Food` there instead of dedicated models?

Comment: @xyres Well my idea behind this is that a Product has similar and non-similar attributes.  A ```Car``` and a ```CellPhone``` both have the attr 'name', 'price', etc. - but a ```CellPhone``` does not have 'number_of_wheels' (for example), and a ```Car``` does not have a 'screen_width' attr.  You know?

Comment: @schwobaseggl ```Product.objects.filter(car__isnull=False)``` works when I know I am looking for Products that are Cars, but what if I don't know? What if I just want to grab every single Product in the database?

Comment: `Product.objects.all()`? What is the issue?

Comment: @schwobaseggl How do you know if a ```Product``` is a ```Car```, ```CellPhone```, or ```Food```?

Comment: Maybe give `Product` a method/property where you try to access `car`, `food`, etc. and catch the exception until you find the one.